# JSONObject Using Singleton

Tags: java, json, design-patterns, singleton

In my project I am using JSON object to sent responce to client.
My `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
```

Every time I am creating an json Object using `new` key word.
I don't want to create using `new` key word.
for this Can I implement `Singleton pattern` for this??

My `Singletone` Class code:

```
public class SingletonInstance {


        private static SingletonInstance instance = new SingletonInstance ();


        private SingletonUmtInstance() {

        }

        // Get the only object available
        public static JSONObject getInstance() {

            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new JSONObject();
                return instance;
            } else {
                return instance;
            }

        }
}
```

to Create an instance I'll use:

```
JSONObject DBCon = SingletonInstance.getInstance();
```

Is this the correct way??

Comment: I don't think this is a proper place for this question

Comment: I just want to know that am I using correct approach..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton design pattern restricts the instantiation and makes sure that only one instance of the class exists in the JVM.

In other terms, when you implement Singleton, the purpose is to make sure that you use the very same instance each time you invoke the getInstance() method.

Regarding your code, the condition `if (instance == null)` is useless and your `getInstance()` method is equivalent to :

```
public static JSONObject getInstance() {
      return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Imen, I have removed the condition `if (instance == null)` , Just want to know am I using correct approach.

Comment: If you want to use the same instance each time then it's the correct approach. If you need a new instance each time, then  Singleton is not right for you.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the approach from creating new object to singleton or static way, make sure the application is not used in multithreaded environment.

You would pass the json string to JSONObject constructor means it is holding the state. Changing it to singleton or static leads to inconsistent data in multithreaded environment.

Use enum for singleton implementation.

Comment: Hi Prasanna, My application is not in multithread environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code snippet:

```
public enum SingletonEnum {

    INSTANCE; 

    public static JSONObject getJsonObject() {        
        return new JSONObject();    
    }
}
```

Get the instance using

```
SingletonEnum singleton = SingletonEnum.INSTANCE;
```

Use the hashcode method in object class to make sure it remains same irrespective of 'n' number of times it was called.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
public class SingletonInstance {

    private SingletonInstance() { }        

    private static class Holder {
       private static final SingletonInstance INSTANCE = new SingletonInstance();
    }

    public static SingletonInstance getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

This implementation is thread-safe as well.